# Implement Multi-project gitlab pipeline with common deploy and test stages

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, microservices, gitlab-ci

I have been tasked with implementing a gitlab ci/cd pipeline for a cloud Saas solution. Our product is made up of 4 microservices, each in a separate git project. My goal is to setup a pipeline where committing a change to service A will build/unit test the service, deploy the service in our CI environment, and then trigger our End-to-End test in a separate project. Solving this for a single commit to a single service is pretty simple. I have a POC where after the deploy stage in the gitlab yml, I just use the "trigger" property to trigger the End-to-End test in the e2e test project. My problem is figuring out how to manage this with parallel commits to each project simultaneously.

For example: if someone commits to service A and it's pipeline starts (build -> deploy to CI space -> trigger E2E test). Then while the pipeline is still running, someone commits to service B, triggering it's pipeline (build -> deploy to CI space -> E2E Test), how do I prevent deployment stage for commit to service B from running while E2E still running from commit to service A? Basically I want the deploy stage and E2E stage to hold if a similar stage is running in other pipelines.

Note: there is long standing history with the services being in separate git projects, so if any solution requires reorganizing the projects it would have to be a very compelling reason.

Comment: Your problem is due to limitations of gitlab c.i engine.  If you would use another more flexible c.i engine you could do anything you want.  Anyway, are you able to run shell code or some nodejs script in your gitlab ci?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a separate runner for your end2end pipeline and limit this runner to 1 pipeline a time

see https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section

Also see this Feature Request, which requests the feature you are looking for:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/41560

There are several other workarounds described.